# Regex in SQL Server to check whitespaces

Tags: sql-server, regex

I am checking for invalid names(names with special characters) in SQL Server with the following code

```
select First_Name 
from sc.Name 
where First_Name LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%';
```

How to add the check for leading and trailing whitespaces?

Comment: yes like that but what should be the alternative to regex to identify wide range of patterns?

Comment: Your predicate should work for trailing and leading spaces also

Comment: So, no French, German, Swedish, Norwegian, Spanish names, or English names with a dash?

Comment: Correct!...That's what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no native *Regex* in SQL Server, but there is [pattern matching](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). An easy way to select columns that end or start with white space would be:

```
SELECT myColumn 
FROM myTable 
WHERE (myColumn LIKE '% ') 
   OR (myColumn LIKE ' %') 
   OR (myColumn LIKE '%[^a-z]%')
```

A quite "heavy" search, but for a one-time query it'll work.

Of course, if you are looking for leading AND trailing white spaces, and the requirement is really that it has both, then you could use:

```
(myColumn LIKE ' %[^a-z]% ')
```

Or any combination of the above to suit your needs.

Comment: Nice, But using `OR` make it slow ;).

Comment: @shA.t yes, but if he wants all combos, OR is needed. It wouldn't have to be `like` though, but it's simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `First_Name <> LTRIM(RTRIM(First_Name))` for checking leading and trailing white-spaces, like this:

```
SELECT First_Name 
FROM sc.Name 
WHERE First_Name LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%' 
  AND First_Name <> LTRIM(RTRIM(First_Name))
```

Comment: Nice(er) one :) except the AND should probably be an OR to get all 'false' name combos

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table a(b varchar(50))
insert into a VALUES('   sadf'),('asdg   ')

select b from a where b LIKE '[^a-zA-Z]%' or  b LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]';
```

Comment: A value like `'asd#$a'`  will be considered valid in your answer which is incorrect as per OP