# Dutch zipcodes regex in SQL Server 2014 always returns 0

Tags: sql-server, regex

I might be missing something. I have to check Dutch zipcodes, but I got some user entered data in my database. I want to check if the zipcode can be an actual zipcode. Format for Dutch zipcodes: 1000-9999AA-ZZ

So any integer between 1000 and 9999 in combination with 2 lettres can be a valid zipcode (there are some additional parameters, but I am not worrying about them for now).

I didn't get my regex to work with this code:

```
 iif(ZipCode like '^[1-9][0-9]{3}\s[a-zA-Z]{2}$',1,0) as MatchIndicator
```

Yet it always returns zero.

I even tried it with a simpler regex

```
iif(ZipCode like '^[1-9]',1,0) as MatchIndicator
```

Returns 0 everytime as well.

I found myself an alternative, but I think the regex code is better to use in the long run for more complicated text.

Alternative

```
case when LEFT(ZipCode,1) between '1' and '9'
                    and substring(ZipCode,2,1) between '0' and '9'
                    and substring(ZipCode,3,1) between '0'and '9'
                    and substring(ZipCode,4,1) between '0' and '9'
                    and substring(ZipCode,5,1) between 'A' and 'Z'
                    and substring(ZipCode,6,1) between 'A' and 'Z' then 1 else 0 end as MatchIndicator
```

And

```
patindex('[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-z][a-zA-z]',ZipCode)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you think SQL server supports regex out of the box?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30232096/15541

Comment: your `regex` is correct if you are not concerned of spaces between numbers and alphabets..can't say about `sql-server` support of `regex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support 'proper' regex. So how about:

```
CREATE TABLE  #Test (Postcode VARCHAR(6))
INSERT INTO #Test
VALUES
    ('1234AZ'),
    ('9876ZQ'),
    ('1900Sz'),
    ('ABCDe1'),
    ('XwYx1A'),
    ('5000A1')


SELECT 
    PostCode,
    CASE WHEN 
        TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(PostCode, 1, 4) AS INT) BETWEEN 1000 AND 9999 
        AND
        PATINDEX('%[A-Z][A-Z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin, SUBSTRING(PostCode, 5, 2)) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END IsValid
FROM #Test


PostCode IsValid
-------- -----------
1234AZ   1
9876ZQ   1
1900Sz   0
ABCDe1   0
XwYx1A   0
5000A1   0
```